# What should I put in my updating.php when I need to update users status if online or offline every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi I've made a messaging feature,it displays the receivers of the message in an account, beside the receiver's name is a green or red dot, for online or offline, it is successful when I log in 2 accounts and messaged each other, when I open the first account, the other account is offline, when I open the second account, the other is online, what my problem is I want to update their status in every five seconds so that their dot will be accurate whenever they log out or log in. I have made a javascript and ajax below this page left-col.php and I've tried copying the whole code, putting it to updating.php but it did not work, what should be the appropriate data inorder to update user receiver status in every 5 seconds inside the updating.php? and also, does my the javascript and ajax needs a library to be included that's why it didn't work? Please help.

```
<?php 
require('connection.php');
$user_name=$_SESSION['username'];
$user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header("LOCATION: index.php");
}else{
    $advance_time=time()+15;
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM status WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE status SET status='$advance_time' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    }else{
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO status(user_id,status) VALUES ('$user_id','$advance_time')");
    }
}
?>
<div id="left-col-container">
<div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.getElementById('new-message').style.display='block'" class="white-back">
<p align="center">New Message </p>
</div>

<?php 

$q='SELECT DISTINCT `receiver_name`,`sender_name`,`date_time`
FROM `messages` WHERE 
`sender_name`="'.$_SESSION['username'].'" OR
`receiver_name`="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"
ORDER BY `date_time` DESC';
$e='SELECT * from messages';
$r=mysqli_query($con,$q);


if($r){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r)>0){
        $counter=0;
        $added_user=array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
            $sender_name=$row['sender_name'];
            $receiver_name=$row['receiver_name'];
            $timestamp=$row['date_time'];
            if($_SESSION['username']==$sender_name){
                //add the receiver_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if(in_array($receiver_name,$added_user)){
                    //dont add receiver_name because
                    //he is already added
                }else{
                    //add the receiver_name
                    ?>
                    <div class="grey-back">
                    <img src="images/s.jpg" class="image"/>
                    <?php 
                    echo '<a href="?user='.$receiver_name.'">'.$receiver_name.'</a>';
                   $fetch_content=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id`");
                    while($row_fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)){
                        $time=$row_fetch[5];
                        if($time<= time()){
                            $status = "<img src='images/r.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }else{
                            $status= "<img src='images/a.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }
                    }
                     echo $status;
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    //as receiver_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user=array($counter=>$receiver_name);
                    //increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }elseif($_SESSION['username']==$receiver_name){
                //add the sender_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if(in_array($sender_name,$added_user)){
                    //dont add sender_name because
                    //he is already added
                }else{
                    //add the sender_name
                    ?>
                    <div class="grey-back">
                    <img src="images/s.jpg" class="image"/>
                    <?php echo '<a href="?user='.$sender_name.'">'.$sender_name.'</a>';
                      $fetch_content=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id`");
                    while($row_fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)){
                        $time=$row_fetch[5];
                        if($time<= time()){
                            $status = "<img src='images/r.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }else{
                            $status= "<img src='images/a.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }
                    }
                     echo $status;
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    //as sender_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user=array($counter=>$sender_name);
                    //increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            }
        }
        else{
        //no message sent
        echo 'no user';
        }
    }else{
    //query problem
    echo $q;
}
?>



<!-- end of left-col-container -->
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" id="from_user_id">
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){updating_status()},5000);
function updating_status(){
    let this_user = $('#from_user_id').val(); 
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "updating.php",
        data: {from_user:this_user},
    success: function(response){
        $('#content').html(response);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: ajax required jquery to run

Comment: yes I made the script, its below

Comment: jquery should be included before the $.ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the $_SESSION in all pages

Updating.php code:

```
<?php 
require('connection.php'); 
session_start(); 

$user_name = $_SESSION['username']; 
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; 
if(isset($_REQUEST['from_user'])){ 
$advance_time=time()+15; 
$user_id = $_REQUEST['from_user']; 
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM status WHERE user_id='$user_id'"); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){ 
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE status SET status='$advance_time' WHERE user_id='$user_id'"); 
} 
}else{ 
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO status(user_id,status) VALUES ('$user_id','$advance_time')"); 
} 

$html_left_div = ''; 
$html_left_div .='<div id="left-col-container"> 
<div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.getElementById(\'new-message\').style.display=\'block\'" class="white-back"> 
<p align="center">New Message </p> 
</div>'; 

$q = 'SELECT DISTINCT `receiver_name`,`sender_name`,`date_time` 
FROM `messages` WHERE 
`sender_name`="' . $_SESSION['username'] . '" OR 
`receiver_name`="' . $_SESSION['username'] . '" 
ORDER BY `date_time` DESC'; 
$e = 'SELECT * from messages'; 
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q); 
// echo $q; 
if ($r) { 
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) { 
$counter = 0; 
$added_user = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { 
$sender_name = $row['sender_name']; 
$receiver_name = $row['receiver_name']; 
$timestamp = $row['date_time']; 
if ($_SESSION['username'] == $sender_name) { 
//add the receiver_name but only once 
//so to do that check the user in array 
if (in_array($receiver_name, $added_user)) { 
//dont add receiver_name because 
//he is already added 
} else { 
//add the receiver_name 

$html_left_div .='<div class="grey-back first"> 
<img src="s.jpg" class="image"/> 
<a href="?user=' . $receiver_name . '">' . $receiver_name . '</a>'; 
$fetch_content = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id` WHERE user_name = '$receiver_name'"); 
while ($row_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)) { 
    $time = $row_fetch[5]; 
    if ($time <= time()) { 
        $status ='<img src=\'r.png\' height=\'10\' width=\'10\' style=\'float:right\'>'; 
    } else { 
        $status ='<img src=\'a.png\' height=\'10\' width=\'10\' style=\'float:right\'>'; 
    } 
} 

$html_left_div .= $status.'</div>'; 

//as receiver_name added so 
///add it to the array as well 
$added_user = array($counter => $receiver_name); 
//increment the counter 
$counter++; 
} 
} elseif ($_SESSION['username'] == $receiver_name) { 
//add the sender_name but only once 
//so to do that check the user in array 
if (in_array($sender_name, $added_user)) { 
//dont add sender_name because 
//he is already added 
} else { 
//add the sender_name 
$html_left_div .='<div class="grey-back second"> 
<img src="s.jpg" class="image"/> 
<a href="?user=' . $sender_name . '">' . $sender_name . '</a>'; 
$fetch_content = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id` WHERE user_name = '$sender_name'"); 
while ($row_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)) { 
$time = $row_fetch[5]; 
if ($time <= time()) { 
$status ='<img src=\'r.png\' height=\'10\' width=\'10\' style=\'float:right\'>'; 
} else { 
$status ='<img src=\'a.png\' height=\'10\' width=\'10\' style=\'float:right\'>'; 
} 
} 

$html_left_div .= $status.'</div>'; 
//as sender_name added so 
///add it to the array as well 
$added_user = array($counter => $sender_name); 
//increment the counter 
$counter++; 
} 
} 
} 
} else { 
//no message sent 
echo 'no user'; 
} 
} else { 
//query problem 
echo $q; 
} 

$html_left_div .='</div>'; 
echo $html_left_div;
```

Left-col.php code:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
session_start();

$user_name = $_SESSION['username'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("LOCATION: index.php");
} else {
    $advance_time = time() + 15;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM status WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE status SET status='$advance_time' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    } else {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO status(user_id,status) VALUES ('$user_id','$advance_time')");
    }
}
?>
<div id="left-col-container">
    <div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.getElementById('new-message').style.display='block'" class="white-back">
    <p align="center">New Message </p>
    </div>

<?php

$q = 'SELECT DISTINCT `receiver_name`,`sender_name`,`date_time`
FROM `messages` WHERE
`sender_name`="' . $_SESSION['username'] . '" OR
`receiver_name`="' . $_SESSION['username'] . '"
ORDER BY `date_time` DESC';
$e = 'SELECT * from messages';
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);

if ($r) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
        $counter = 0;
        $added_user = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
            $sender_name = $row['sender_name'];
            $receiver_name = $row['receiver_name'];
            $timestamp = $row['date_time'];
            if ($_SESSION['username'] == $sender_name) {
//add the receiver_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if (in_array($receiver_name, $added_user)) {
//dont add receiver_name because
                    //he is already added
                } else {
//add the receiver_name
                    ?>
<div class="grey-back">
<img src="images/s.jpg" class="image"/>
<?php
echo '<a href="?user=' . $receiver_name . '">' . $receiver_name . '</a>';
                    $fetch_content = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id`");
                    while ($row_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)) {
                        $time = $row_fetch[5];
                        if ($time <= time()) {
                            $status = "<img src='images/r.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        } else {
                            $status = "<img src='images/a.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo $status;
                    ?>
</div>
<?php
//as receiver_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user = array($counter => $receiver_name);
//increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            } elseif ($_SESSION['username'] == $receiver_name) {
//add the sender_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if (in_array($sender_name, $added_user)) {
//dont add sender_name because
                    //he is already added
                } else {
//add the sender_name
                    ?>
<div class="grey-back">
<img src="images/s.jpg" class="image"/>
<?php echo '<a href="?user=' . $sender_name . '">' . $sender_name . '</a>';
                    $fetch_content = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id`");
                    while ($row_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)) {
                        $time = $row_fetch[5];
                        if ($time <= time()) {
                            $status = "<img  src='images/r.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        } else {
                            $status = "<img src='images/a.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo $status;
                    ?>
</div>
<?php
//as sender_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user = array($counter => $sender_name);
//increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
//no message sent
        echo 'no user';
    }
} else {
//query problem
    echo $q;
}
?>



<!-- end of left-col-container -->
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" id="from_user_id">
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){updating_status()},5000);
function updating_status(){
let this_user = $('#from_user_id').val();
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "updating.php",
data: {from_user:this_user},
success: function(response){
    $('#left-col-container').html(response);
}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Rishab I have a question in your answer. Let's move to the chat we have

Comment: Rishab, check our chat

Comment: do you about google maps? I have a problem, if you do, you can check out our chat

Comment: How to get the location of a coordinate?

Comment: How do we update status in every page anyway? same as what we did in left-col.php? I did it but it did not work

Comment: Just write the simple code in one php page to update user status and add the ajax jquery code pages where you want to use this

Comment: Rishab, I did put what we did at left-col.php in every php page, it did worked first but when I get back to my pc 3 days after, It don't update anymore https://github.com/patrickesguerra/petner , there is the database inside

Comment: please help me with my app, its not going online anymore https://github.com/patrickesguerra/petner

Comment: Okay will check gonna take some time